# List of all allocated objects in Java

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Is it possible in Java to ask the memory manager for a list of all currently allocated objects? The garbage collector must maintain a list like this somewhere. Maybe it's accessible?

Comment: Not through normal Java, but the debugging API probably has a way to do it.